# PowerShell Invoke-Command not passing parameters properly

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I have a PowerShell Script that will invoke a command on a remote server. I'm trying to set this script up so that I can pass in a `service` parameter and it will drop that specific table in MongoDB

```
$service = "DatabaseName"

$username = "username"
$password = "password"

$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $pass

Invoke-Command -ComputerName Remote-Server1 -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $service -ScriptBlock {
    param($service) 
    & 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe' $service --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName Remote-Server2 -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $service -ScriptBlock {
    param($service) 
    & 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe' $service --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'
}
```

If I were to use the following it does not drop the MongoDB database:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe' $service --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'
```

However, If I use the following it works as expected:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe' DatabaseName --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'
```

Why does it work when I hard code that database name but not when I use a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code only needs `$service` in a read-only manner you can use the `Using:`-scope modifier, see additional information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6).

Based on that you can change the code to:

```
$service = "DatabaseName"
$username = "username"
$password = "password"

$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $pass

Invoke-Command -ComputerName Remote-Server1 -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $service -ScriptBlock {
    & 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe' $Using:service --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName Remote-Server2 -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $service -ScriptBlock {
    & 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe' $Using:service --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'
}
```

When performing remote commands via `Invoke-Command` I either use the `Using` modifier of prefix the variables in the `param` block with `remote`. Based on that I can avoid "unwanted" behaviors (as the one you stated above).

So another alternative would be:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Remote-Server1 -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $service -ScriptBlock {
    param($remoteService)
    & 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe' $remoteService --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'
}
```